# Print Html Page with CSS

Tags: html, css, datatables

I have an app in which I have invoices. I am trying to give user a page where he can see the detail invoice and also print it. The issue is with the CSS for that print page.

I have tables in there. I am using [jQuery DataTables](http://datatables.net/). Is there an easy way or tutorial to follow for writing CSS for the print page? I can leave using table for that page but I would prefer if I can keep using tables.

Comment: Are you asking about print preview window in jQuery DataTables with TableTools extenstion or printing the page with table in general?

Comment: With Jquery Datatables. So my page has some information on the top and then some data in datatables. I want to print that whole page including both the information and datatables.

Comment: Do you refer to TableTools with Print preview as seen in [this example](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/TableTools/examples/simple.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create print styles through a media query like this:

```
@media print {
    /* Styles go in here */
}
```

You can read more on media queries at [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp) and more on the print query [here](http://benfrain.com/create-print-styles-using-css3-media-queries/).

Answer (score 1):

TableTools extension adds a special class `DTTT_Print` ([reference](http://datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/buttons#print%20)) to the `<body>` element, see [this example](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/TableTools/examples/simple.html).

For example, to hide an element with class `sidebar` both in print preview window and on paper add the following rules to your CSS file.

```
body.DTTT_Print .sidebar { display: none !important; } 

@media print {
 .sidebar { display: none !important; } 
}
```

First rule will hide `.sidebar` in TableTools print preview mode. Second rule will ensure that `.sidebar` is hidden if the page is actually printed.